# Pandas - count on specific column and get top N as list

Tags: python, pandas, list, performance

I got a `Pandas dataframe` and want to `groupby` and count on 'animal' column to fetch the top 3 as a list:

```
> df
animal  age  weight  length
0     hamster    5      13       2
1     hamster   14      11       4
2         cat    3      14       4
3         cat    5       6       4
4       snake    7      14       8
5         cat    4      12       5
6     hamster   11      12       9
7       snake   14       9       7
8     hamster    1       5       9
9   alligator    4      13       2
10      snake   12       7       6
11    hamster   14      10       2
12      snake    7      14       7
13  alligator    4      10       2

 > df.groupby("animal")['animal'].count().nlargest(3)
animal
hamster    5
snake      4
cat        3
```

Is this an efficient way and also how do I go about convert the resulting top 3 to an ordered list ie, `['hamster', 'snake', 'cat']`?

Comment: Its a dupe. You can use value_counts, df.animal.value_counts()[:3].index.tolist()

Comment: That works, thanks: df["animal"].value_counts()[:3].index.tolist()